# php - select * with same ID and put each one to different variables

Tags: php, mysql

There is a table like this:

```
id  imageid path     tourid   defaultimage
1      12    asd134    1           1
2      12    asd212    1           0
3      12    asd354    1           0
4      15    qwe       2           0
```

I need to get all entries with imageid 12 and put all of them into different variables. I could run a query for each one, but I never know how many entries are in the table with same id. Sometimes it is 1 and sometimes it is a lot.

I have tried this:

```
  $result3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages WHERE tourid='$tourid' AND defaultimage = '1'");
         while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
         $imagepath = $row3['imagepath'];
         echo  $imagepath;
         }




        $result4 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages WHERE tourid='$tourid' AND defaultimage = '0' LIMIT 1");
         while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
         $imagepath2 = $row4['imagepath'];
$image2id = $row4['imageid'];

    echo $imagepath2 ;

         }

$result5 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages WHERE tourid='$tourid' AND imageid!='{$image2id}' AND defaultimage = '0'  LIMIT 1 ");
         while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {
         $imagepath3 = $row5['imagepath'];


    echo $imagepath3 ;

         }
```

Comment: I need to select all path where imageid=12 and put all of them into different variables as:
$imagepath1
$imagepath2 

and etc. where assigning into variables may be implemented through array.

Comment: J doe check answer and mark one which is correct

Comment: Are you there? can you tell status? what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$imagepath = array();
$result3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages WHERE tourid='$tourid'");
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
        $imagepath[] = $row3['path'];
    }
echo "<pre/>";print_r($imagepath);
```

**Use this `$imagepath` array anywhere you want.It will be useful for future reference too.**

Comment: and how to get each path of each imageid?

Comment: `$result3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages");`

Comment: Thanks Anant! Worked perfectly

Comment: Welcome @J.Doe. don't forgot to up-vote when you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you need variable:-

```
$i=1
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
    $imagepath.$i = $row3['imagepath'];
    $i++
}
```

but good approach is use array :-

```
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      $imagepath[] = $row3['imagepath'];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @Rahautos

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tourimages WHERE imageid='$imageid'"); 
    $imagepath = [];
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
       $imagepath[] = $row3['imagepath']; 
    } 
    print_r($imagepath);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @sanjay